# Cannot confirm my ERC20 coin balance with geth.console

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, erc-20

In geth console, I want to check the balance of my ERC20 coin (called 'DPI' at contract address below).
I do not want to use etherscan, rather I want to be able to check it offline.

I think how I assign the tokenABI is wrong but cannot figure out how to fix it.

```
var tokenABI='[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address[]","name":"_components","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"int256[]","name":"_units","type":"int256[]"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"_modules","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"contract IController","name":"_controller","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_manager","type":"address"},{"internalType":"string","name":"_name","type":"string"},{"internalType":"string","name":"_symbol","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"}],"name":"ComponentAdded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"}],"name":"ComponentRemoved","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"_realUnit","type":"int256"}],"name":"DefaultPositionUnitEdited","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_positionModule","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"ExternalPositionDataEdited","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_positionModule","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"_realUnit","type":"int256"}],"name":"ExternalPositionUnitEdited","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_target","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bytes","name":"_returnValue","type":"bytes"}],"name":"Invoked","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"_newManager","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"_oldManager","type":"address"}],"name":"ManagerEdited","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_module","type":"address"}],"name":"ModuleAdded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_module","type":"address"}],"name":"ModuleInitialized","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_module","type":"address"}],"name":"ModuleRemoved","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_module","type":"address"}],"name":"PendingModuleRemoved","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_positionModule","type":"address"}],"name":"PositionModuleAdded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_positionModule","type":"address"}],"name":"PositionModuleRemoved","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"_newMultiplier","type":"int256"}],"name":"PositionMultiplierEdited","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"}],"name":"addComponent","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_positionModule","type":"address"}],"name":"addExternalPositionModule","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_module","type":"address"}],"name":"addModule","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_account","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_quantity","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"components","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"controller","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract IController","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"_realUnit","type":"int256"}],"name":"editDefaultPositionUnit","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_positionModule","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"editExternalPositionData","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_positionModule","type":"address"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"_realUnit","type":"int256"}],"name":"editExternalPositionUnit","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"_newMultiplier","type":"int256"}],"name":"editPositionMultiplier","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getComponents","outputs":[{"internalType":"address[]","name":"","type":"address[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"}],"name":"getDefaultPositionRealUnit","outputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"","type":"int256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_positionModule","type":"address"}],"name":"getExternalPositionData","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"}],"name":"getExternalPositionModules","outputs":[{"internalType":"address[]","name":"","type":"address[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_positionModule","type":"address"}],"name":"getExternalPositionRealUnit","outputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"","type":"int256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getModules","outputs":[{"internalType":"address[]","name":"","type":"address[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getPositions","outputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"address","name":"component","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"module","type":"address"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"unit","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"positionState","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"internalType":"struct ISetToken.Position[]","name":"","type":"tuple[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"}],"name":"getTotalComponentRealUnits","outputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"","type":"int256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"initializeModule","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_target","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"invoke","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_returnValue","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"}],"name":"isComponent","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_module","type":"address"}],"name":"isExternalPositionModule","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_module","type":"address"}],"name":"isInitializedModule","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"isLocked","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_module","type":"address"}],"name":"isPendingModule","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"lock","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"locker","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"manager","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_account","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_quantity","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"moduleStates","outputs":[{"internalType":"enum ISetToken.ModuleState","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"modules","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"positionMultiplier","outputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"","type":"int256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"}],"name":"removeComponent","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_component","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_positionModule","type":"address"}],"name":"removeExternalPositionModule","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_module","type":"address"}],"name":"removeModule","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_module","type":"address"}],"name":"removePendingModule","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_manager","type":"address"}],"name":"setManager","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"unlock","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]';
var tokenContract = eth.contract(tokenABI).at("0x1494CA1F11D487c2bBe4543E90080AeBa4BA3C2b");
tokenContract.methods.balanceOf("<My Metamask Hex Address>").call();
```

However, I get the following error :

> TypeError: Object has no member 'filter'
> at web3.js:2849:24(7)
> at web3.js:3060:27(14)
> at :1:46(10)